# Unix Shell Renaming Excel Tabs

Tags: bash, unix, ksh

I have a excel with multiple tabs and the name of the sheets coming as

> sheet0, sheet1, .... sheet10

I wanted to rename those tabs how to do it in UNIX shell using **ksh** or **bash**.

Please note that by tabs of excel , my context is the name of excel sheet that is getting displayed at bottom of excel.for generating excel I am using array with syntax `{arrayelements [*]}` under a while loop.

Comment: Welcome. What have you tried? Please post code and error message. See [ask] for support.

Answer (score 0):

If I may hope that you are flexible enough to rename Excel sheets from the command-line and not necessarily using only shell (e.g Bash) constructs then a lot can be accomplished with the use of Python modules for Excel files. See: [here](http://www.python-excel.org/).

Comment: I wonder why it is so. As far as I know Bash does not have in-built support to parse Excel files.

Answer (score 0):

```
a=$(cat test.xml)
b=${a//sheet0/whatever_you_want}
echo "$b" > test.xml
```

or in a loop:

```
for ((x=0;x<=10;x++)) do
   a=$(cat test.xml)
   b=${a//sheet$x/whatever_you_want$x}
   echo "$b" > test.xml
done
```

This loops through the sheet names and replaces them with whatever you want.
As far as I can tell, this works for .xml, but not .xls or .xlsx files, so it'll need to be first saved as a .xml file.

**Edit based on comments**
Using a linux command that comes with gnumeric `ssconvert` you can convert an .xlsx file to .xml and, after changing the sheet names, from .xml to .xlsx:

```
ssconvert --export-type=Gnumeric_XmlIO:sax:0 test.xlsx test.xml
ssconvert --export-type=Gnumeric_Excel:xlsx test.xml test.xlsx
```

Documentation here: http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/ssconvert1.html

That file conversion is a bit too complex for bash alone.

Comment: is there is any way to convert .xml to .xlsx

Comment: Is there is any way to read each sheets of xlsx separately,if it is possible then we can achieve the same in xlsx

Comment: it looks like `ssconvert` can be used to convert .xml to .xlsx: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158254/convert-csv-to-xls-file-on-linux. If you look at the code within the .xml file you'll see the sheets are distinct, so yes you should be able to read each sheet (and the data within) separately.

Comment: Okay, see the edit. That workflow works for me. I don't think the file conversion can be done in pure bash like the sheet renaming, but it can at least be done with a command in linux. You'll need to have `gnumeric` installed to use `ssconvert`.

Comment: `gnumeric` will work on all unix operating systems. I tested this loop and commands on mac osx and debian. If you need all of this in bash alone... not so sure that can be done.